# Implement a simple calculator GUI using Swing controls

Tags: java, swing, awt, calculator, jtextfield

I want to make a simple calculator using Swing components with only one `JTextField`. In the `actionPerformed` method where `ActionEvent`s will be implemented, I want to know: what logic is required to perform a particular action when user Enter the specific button?

Here's my code.

```java
package calculator1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import java.awt.event.*;

class MyFirstGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    int val1 = 0;
    int val2 = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);

    JButton b1 = new JButton("+");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("*");
    JButton b3 = new JButton("/");
    JButton b4 = new JButton("=");
    int n1, n2;

    public MyFirstGUI() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(500, 500);
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Result");

        add(l1);
        add(t1);
        add(b1);
        add(b2);
        add(b3);
        add(b4);

        b1.addActionListener(this);
        b2.addActionListener(this);
        b3.addActionListener(this);
        b4.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int val1, val2, sum = 0;

        val1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        if (e.getSource() == b1) {
            t1.setText("");

        }
        if (e.getSource() == b4) {
            val2 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
            sum = val1 + val2;
            t1.setText("" + sum);
        }
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyFirstGUI p = new MyFirstGUI();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean like how to add, subtract, multiply and divide? Are you asking about what is action performed?

Comment: Why having only one input field (JTextField) if all arithmetic operations involve two values?

Comment: I'm asking what logic is required to perform certain actions like b1 for add, b2 for multiply and the rest. I tried using ifs and else but none of them worked inside the ActionPerformed method

Comment: You read text from JTextField perform calculation and set output to JTextField.

Comment: yeah, I did that for Sum but I've no idea how's this gonna work for the rest operations i tried using if else for the others but that's not working

Comment: It will be same. Also Name your button to something meaningful.

Comment: See also this [calculator example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441804/418556).  It uses `ScriptEngine` to evaluate the expression in the text field.

Comment: @uminder, *Why having only one input field (JTextField) if all arithmetic operations involve two values?* - this is the way calculators work.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help you!

```
       import java.util.Arrays;

    import javax.swing.*;
       import java.awt.*;

     import java.awt.event.*;

     class MyFirstGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

int val1;
int val2;
int sum = 0;
int num=0;
JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);

JButton b1 = new JButton("+");
JButton b2 = new JButton("*");
JButton b3 = new JButton("/");
JButton b4 = new JButton("=");
int n1, n2;

public MyFirstGUI() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(500, 500);
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Result");

    add(l1);
    add(t1);
    add(b1);
    add(b2);
    add(b3);
    add(b4);

    b1.addActionListener(this);
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    b3.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String[]a = {"+","*","/"};
    if (e.getSource() == b1) {
        val1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        t1.setText("");
        b4.addActionListener(this);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == b2) {
        val1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        t1.setText("");
        num=1;
    b4.addActionListener(this);
     }
    else if (e.getSource() == b3) {
        val1 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        t1.setText("");
        num=2;
      b4.addActionListener(this);
    }
    else if (e.getSource() == b4) {
        val2 = Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());

        switch(a[num]) {
        case "+":
            sum = val1+val2;
            System.out.println(val1+val2);
            t1.setText(sum+"");
            break;
        case "*":
            sum = val1*val2;
            System.out.println(val1*val2);
            t1.setText(sum+"");
            break;
        case "/":
            sum = val1/val2;
            System.out.println(val1/val2);
            t1.setText(sum+"");
            break;
        }
       b4.removeActionListener(this);
       val1=0;val2=0;
    }
}
 }

  class answer4 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyFirstGUI p = new MyFirstGUI();
  }
 }
```

i added for all too.